# Display custom widget to specific product

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3

I created a custom widget. Now I want it to display into the specific product page. Example I have Product 1 and Product 2. I want my custom widget to display in Product 1 but not in Product 2. How can I achieve this? It seems that going to the admin->catalog->product and selecting the product does not work because there are no option to select the widget I want. What will be the best or correct approach to do this?

Note: My widget displays a form and I want that form to only display to a specific product. Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: You should be able to choose where to show each widget? https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/cms/widget-static-block.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set it on **Widget's Storefront Properties**.
You click on **Add Layout Updates** → **Display on**, then choose **All Product Types** then select **Specific Products**
From there set the product where you want your widget to be visible or available

Comment: Wow thanks dude really save me here.